# Question On Sums of Squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

On page 154 of "Elementary Number Theory" by Underwood Dudley, problem 8 states

> If $n=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$, show that by suitable ordering and choices of sign we can get $x+y+z$ to be a multiple of $3$.

What does "get $x+y+z$ to be a multiple of $3$." mean in that sentence ? Do I have to show that, in any sum of four squares, three of the integers add up to a multiple of $3$ ?

Comment: Sum of four squares? There are only three being summed.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: The question is still unclear — what is there about the question that prevents $x=1$, $y=2$, $z=3$ or even all three equal to $1$?

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: I think you may use pigeonhole principle

Comment: @Théophile I don't think that is what it's asking.  If we have $w=x=2\text{ and }y=z=3,$ there is no way to choose $3$ numbers that add up to a multiple of $3$,  However, $2^2+2^2+3^2+3^2=26=0^2+0^2+1^2+5^2,$ and $0+1+5$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Perhaps the author meant "find another representation of $n$ using $x$,$y$z$ and $w$ where three integers are add up to a multiple of 3"? (i.e., replace $x$ with $-x$ etc.)

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I see now.

Comment: *"Do I have to show that, in any sum of four squares, three of the integers add up to a multiple of 3?"* Yes, this is what the question is asking. More accurately, three of the roots, either positive or negative, add up to a multiple of 3.

Comment: @Théophile But the idea of signs is good.  We could equally well choose $-2,2,3$ in the example I gave.  That may well be the way to do the problem.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I think that will be the right trick.

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Comment: Squares can be either $0\pmod3$ or $1\pmod3$. So we are writing $n$ as a sum of $4$ numbers that are $0\pmod3$ or $1\pmod3$. The only time when we cannot simply collect $3$ ones or $3$ zeros from $x,y,z,w$ is if $2$ are one and $2$ are zero. Then we can change the sign on $1$ of the ones so that $(x,y,z,w)$ is a permutation of $(1,-1,0,0)\pmod3$. It is easy to then pick $(1,-1,0)\pmod3$ that will sum to a multiple of $3$.